# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,boolean given in C:

Tags: php

Please help me. Im a newbie in php programming.
mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pjs\checklogin.php on line 26
Wrong Username or Password

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: This is not the way to post a question. You need to show some of the code you have tried. You need to show where you are stuck and what you have tried so far to rectify the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your select query because when there is problem in query **mysql_num_rows()** will give this error.